# Will older versions of iLife (like 06 or 08 or 09) run on Lion

Tags: macos, ilife

I'm looking and don't see any official word yet from Apple - I wondered if any web sites have reported whether these older versions work a little or at all (or perfectly well with only some little errors).

The [Roaring Apps table](http://roaringapps.com/apps%3atable) lists only iLife 11 versions and my attempts at the top 20 results for several google searches shows a lot of content farms gaming the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iLife '08 is running fine on my OSX 10.7 computer.

Most non-PowerPC apps will run fine in Lion, so I expect all the versions you mention will be fine.

Comment: Excellent - I think it's safe to put 06 to bed (but was curious.) If you could hop back and let us know of any issues should you discover any - that would be great! I really appreciate the report.

Comment: Sure thing. Will do!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know from experience, but there are some conversations about it out there. Check these sites:

http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1145755.html

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3125500?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I appreciate the links. Neither have any concrete information and just general speculation. Both are from before Lion was released, so I'll keep looking for articles that at least speak from experience on actually running things on Lion as shipped.